# save_post action not triggering in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

I trying to hook a function into `save_post` like this:

```
function my_function($post_ID) {
    var_dump($post_ID);
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
```

The problem is that it's not doing anything, I'm using the `var_dump` as example but it should at least print the `$post_ID` variable when I edit/publish a post.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you using this? As far as I know, the "save_post" hook is only executed in the admin section, so you won't see anything if you are trying to run this outside of it.

Comment: It would be on my `functions.php` file, but it should fire when I save or update a post inside the admin area.

Comment: Ok. It may actually be running, but you are just doing a "var_dump()" which might be getting printed, but you just can't see it.

I would check the code to see if you can see the var dump in there, or add more complex code in there (such as an actual "update_post_meta()" , or even an "exit()" to see if the code stops.

Let me know if you make any progress, I might be able to help.